# d3 labelled horizontal chart with labels and animation

Tags: d3.js

I am working on a d3js horizontal chart - the designers are specific in having the labels this way.

I've built the following - but would like to model it more on older code that had animation properties.

//current chart
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZmJzXZ

//static vertical chart http://jsfiddle.net/pg886/201/

//animated vertical chart http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/12073/

-- d3js code

```
   var data = [{
            "name": "Apples",
            "value": 20,
    },
        {
            "name": "Bananas",
            "value": 12,
    },
        {
            "name": "Grapes",
            "value": 19,
    },
        {
            "name": "Lemons",
            "value": 5,
    },
        {
            "name": "Limes",
            "value": 16,
    },
        {
            "name": "Oranges",
            "value": 26,
    },
        {
            "name": "Pears",
            "value": 30,
    }];

    //sort bars based on value
    data = data.sort(function (a, b) {
        return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value);
    })

    //set up svg using margin conventions - we'll need plenty of room on the left for labels
    var margin = {
        top: 15,
        right: 25,
        bottom: 15,
        left: 60
    };

    var width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var svg = d3.select("#graphic").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width])
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
            return d.value;
        })]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundBands([height, 0], .3)
        .domain(data.map(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        }));

    //make y axis to show bar names
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        //no tick marks
        .tickSize(0)
        .orient("right");

    var gy = svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)

    var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "bars")


    //append rects
    bars.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name);
        })
        .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("width", function (d) {
            return x(d.value);
        });

    //add a value label to the right of each bar
    bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "label")
        //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
        .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
        })
        //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
        .attr("x", function (d) {
            return x(d.value) + 3;
        })
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.value;
        });

    var labels =         
        bars.append("text")
        .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("y", function (d) {
            return y(d.name) + y.rangeBand() / 2 - 30;
        })
    .attr("x", 0)
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.name;
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the horizontal chart to have an initial animation on load?

Comment: yes - but also be able to animate if the data changes

Comment: That would require a bit of refactoring, do you need to use version 3 of d3 or can you use the latest version?

Comment: it could be the later version - how does it matter?

Comment: The d3 methods etc have slightly different names in the later version amongst other things, that's why I asked. I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar chart that I've made a few modifications to that might fill your requierments, so I'll be basing my answer of my own code.

I'll just go through the most relevant part of the question and you can just have a look at the code and hopefully figure out how it works yourself.

The inital animation works exactly the same way as in the third link you posted:

```
.transition().duration(speed)
    .delay((_, i) => delay * i)
```

we set a delay so that each bar appear one at a time.

I've also set it up so that you can change the data using the d3js update pattern.

```
    var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data, d => d.name)

    bar.exit().remove();

    bar.enter().insert("g", ".y-axis").append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("fill", "#ccc")
        .attr("x", x(0))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.name))
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .merge(bar)
    .transition().duration(speed)
        .delay((_, i) => delay * i)
        .attr("y", d => y(d.name))
        .attr("width", d => x(d.value) - x(0));
```

Since you didn't specify how you want to update the new data it's just a year filter for now.

Here's all the code:

```js
var init = [
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Apples", "value": 20},
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Bananas","value": 12},
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Grapes", "value": 19},
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Lemons", "value": 5},
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Limes", "value": 16},
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Oranges", "value": 26},
    {"year": "2017", "name": "Pears","value": 30},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Apples", "value": 10},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Bananas","value": 42},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Grapes", "value": 69},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Lemons", "value": 15},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Limes", "value": 26},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Oranges", "value": 36},
    {"year": "2018", "name": "Pears","value": 20}
];

chart(init)

function chart(result) {

 var format = d3.format(",.0f")

 var years = [...new Set(result.map(d => d.year))]
 var fruit = [...new Set(result.map(d => d.name))]

 var options = d3.select("#year").selectAll("option")
  .data(years)
 .enter().append("option")
  .text(d => d)

 var svg = d3.select("#graphic"),
  margin = {top: 25, bottom: 10, left: 50, right: 45},
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([margin.left, width - margin.right])
 
 var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([margin.top, height - margin.bottom])
  .padding(0.1)
  .paddingOuter(0.5)
  .paddingInner(0.5)

 var xAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(0,${margin.top})`)

 var yAxis = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y-axis")
  .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)

 update(d3.select("#year").property("value"), 750, 250)

 function update(input, speed, delay) {

  var data = result.filter(f => f.year == input)

  var sum = d3.sum(data, d => d.value)

  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.value)]).nice()

  svg.selectAll(".x-axis").transition().duration(speed)
   .call(d3.axisTop(x).tickSizeOuter(0));
   
  data.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)

  y.domain(data.map(d => d.name))

  svg.selectAll(".y-axis").transition().duration(speed)
   .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

  yAxis.selectAll("text").remove()
  yAxis.selectAll("line").remove()

  var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
   .data(data, d => d.name)

  bar.exit().remove();

  bar.enter().insert("g", ".y-axis").append("rect")
   .attr("class", "bar")
   .attr("fill", "#ccc")
   .attr("x", x(0))
   .attr("y", d => y(d.name))
   .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
   .merge(bar)
  .transition().duration(speed)
   .delay((_, i) => delay * i)
   .attr("y", d => y(d.name))
   .attr("width", d => x(d.value) - x(0));

  var value = svg.selectAll(".value")
   .data(data, d => d.name)

  value.exit().remove();

  value.enter().append("text")
   .attr("class", "value")
   .attr("opacity", 0)
   .attr("dy", 4)
   .attr("y", d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth() / 2)
   .merge(value)
  .transition().duration(speed)
   .delay((_, i) => delay * i)
   .attr("opacity", 1)
   .attr("y", d => y(d.name) + y.bandwidth() / 2)
   .attr("x", d =>  x(d.value) + 5)
   .text(d => format((d.value / sum) * 100) + " %")

  var name = svg.selectAll(".name")
   .data(data, d => d.name)

  name.exit().remove();

  name.enter().append("text")
   .attr("class", "name")
   .attr("opacity", 0)
   .attr("dy", -5)
   .attr("y", d => y(d.name))
   .merge(name)
  .transition().duration(speed)
   .delay((_, i) => delay * i)
   .attr("opacity", 1)
   .attr("y", d => y(d.name))
   .attr("x", d =>  x(0) + 5)
   .text(d => d.name)
 }

 var select = d3.select("#year")
  .style("border-radius", "5px")
  .on("change", function() {
   update(this.value, 750, 0)
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
  width: 650px;
  font: 12px arial;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg id="graphic" width="600" height="380"></svg><br>

Choose year: 
<select id="year"></select>
```